# GeoDistance query with multiple input points

Tags: elasticsearch, geopoints

I'm fairly new to ES and I am trying to figure out the best way to do this:

- I have A type records indexed with geo points coordinates
- I have B type records indexed with geo points coordinates

I would like to get all B records within 10km of A records

Is this possible without looping through all A records and doing a query for each one ?

Thanks for your help